# iPhone - SQLite using TEXT primary key

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite, core-data, uuid

Does anyone know if I can use a TEXT (UUID) primary key for an SQLite iPhone database?
I am not using CoreData.

Comment: What happens when you tried it?

Comment: Didn't yet tried it because the modifications to the entire project are no in the testing step. I need to be sure everything will work since the deadline is near and the syncronization process with the server is to slow. To optimize it we would like to use UUID as primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite it is allowing you to use TEXT as primary key and if you are using SQLite api you should have no problems.

Comment: Could you look at my other comments? I really need some help assessing this update to my source code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: My reply is considering your last comment from the previous post:sqlite3_last_insert_rowid is not returning you the primary key but the value of a system "hidden" table column. If you want to retrieve then the primary key you can get first the rowid and then build a query like: SELECT your_primary_key FROM your_table WHERE rowid=the_row_id_retrieved_with_sqlite3_last_insert_rowid.

Comment: I don't really understand your reply. I would like to remove the integer row id (primary key) and use only the UUID. Can you explain again your suggestions? Thanks

Comment: You can not remove the ROWID this is a system column. From sqlite documentation: "Every row of every SQLite table has a 64-bit signed integer key that uniquely identifies the row within its table. This integer is usually called the "rowid". The rowid value can be accessed using one of the special case-independent names "rowid", "oid", or "_rowid_" in place of a column name. If a table contains a user defined column named "rowid", "oid" or "_rowid_", then that name always refers the explicitly declared column and cannot be used to retrieve the integer rowid value."

Comment: You can define another primary key of type text to store the UUID but by default you will still have the system rowid. Depends on your system on how many connection it handles, if it is a simple one you can retrieve the last insert using a sql command like: SELECT your_primary_key FROM your_table ORDER BY rowid DESC LIMIT 1;

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use text field as primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (uniqueText VARCHAR NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, text VARCHAR)
```

Some insert:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (uniqueText, text) VALUES ('hello', 'world')
```

Result: OK.

Another insert:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (uniqueText, text) VALUES ('hello', 'world')
```

Result: Error - Column uniqueText is not unique.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot. But what should I do with this SQLite API function: SQLITE_API sqlite3_int64 sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(sqlite3*);? It should return an int64(long) variable. Could I just modify it? Or is there another way to retrieve the primary key of the last inserted row?